# How to pass a variable into regex in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, regex, match

Is there a way to pass a variable into a regex in jQuery/Javascript?

I wanna do something like:

```
var variable_regex = "bar";
var some_string = "foobar";

some_string.match(/variable_regex/);
```

In Ruby you would be able to do:

`some_string.match(/#{variable_regex}/)`

Found a useful post:

[How can I concatenate regex literals in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185510/how-can-i-concatenate-regex-literals-in-javascript)

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's easy:

```
var variable_regex = "bar";
var some_string = "foobar";

some_string.match(variable_regex);
```

Just lose the //. If you want to use complex regexes, you can use string concatenation:

```
var variable_regex = "b.";
var some_string = "foobar";

alert (some_string.match("f.*"+variable_regex));
```

Comment: I had a complex regex and I wanted to interpolate a variable pattern into a hardcoded expression, but I guess I'd just set each regex permutation to a whole variable.

Comment: I don't think you can apply regex options with this version (global, case-insensitive, for instance).  I'd say @Jonathan's answer is more appropriate than this one.

Comment: It also only works with match.  Other calls, like replace, require constructing the regex explicitly.

Answer (score 106):

Javascript doesn't support interpolation like Ruby -- you have to use the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var aString = "foobar";
var pattern = "bar";

var matches = aString.match(new RegExp(pattern));
```

Comment: In the case that we want to apply regex options, we can do: new Regex(pattern, 'gi') for global, case insensitive.

Comment: @Mike 's comment need to be corrected. It should be `new RegExp(pattern[, flags])` not just **Regex**

Comment: ES2015 supports expression interpolation in template strings.

Answer (score 17):

It's easy, you need to create a `RegExp` instance with a variable.
When I searched for the answer, I also wanted this string to being interpolated with regarding variable.

Try it out in a browser console:

```js
const b = 'b';
const result = (new RegExp(`^a${b}c$`)).test('abc');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -8):

Another way to include a variable in a string is through string interpolation. In JavaScript, you can insert or interpolate variables in strings using model literals:

```
var name = "Jack";
var id = 123321;

console.log(`Hello, ${name} your id is ${id}.`);
```

Note: be careful not to confuse quotation marks or apostrophes for the serious accent (`).

You can use in function:

```
function myPhrase(name, id){
   return `Hello, ${name} your id is ${id}.`;
}
```