# jquery match() variable interpolation - complex regexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, interpolation, match

I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695633?sort=newest#sort-top), which was helpful to a point.

Here's the problem. I have a list of users propagated into an element via user click; something like this:

```
<div id="box">
    joe-user
    page-joe-user
    someone-else
    page-someone-else
</div>
```

On click, I want to make sure that the user has not already been clicked into the div. So, I'm doing something like:

```
if ( ! $('#box').html().match(rcpt) )
{
   update_div();
}
else
{
   alert(rcpt+' already exists.');
}
```

However, with existing lack of interpolation that javascript has for regular expressions, is causing my alert to trigger in the use-case where `page-joe-user` is selected and then the user selects `joe-user`, which are clearly not exactly the same.

In Perl I would do something like:

```
if ( $rcpt =~ /^\Qrcpt\E/ )
{
    # code
}
```

All I want to do is change my match() to be:

```
if ( ! $('#box').html().match(/^rcpt/) )
{
    # code
}
```

`if ( ! $('#box').html().match(rcpt) )` seemed a little promising but it, too, fails. Using `new RegExp()` also does not work using concatenation of complex RE syntax within the function IE `$('#box').html().match(new RegExp('^'+rcpt))`. I also tried `$('#box').html().match('/^'+rcpt'/')`. I can only imagine that I'm missing something. I'm pretty new to javascript.

I don't seem to be able to find anything that really addresses such a use-case, here on this site.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `match` function only works on strings, not jQuery objects.

The best way to do this is to put each username into a separate HTML tag.

For example:

```
<ul id="users">
    <li>joe-user</li>
    <li>page-joe-user</li>
    <li>someone-else</li>
    <li>page-someone-else</li>
</ul>
```

You can then write the following:

```
if($('#users li').is(function () { return $(this).text() === rcpt; }))
```

If you want to do it your way, you should call `text()` to get the string inside the element.  (`$('#box').text().match(...)`)

---

**EDIT**: The best way to do this using your HTML would be to split the string.

For example:

```
var userExists = false;
var users = $('#box').text().split(/\r?\n/);

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {   //IE doesn't have indexOf
    if (users[i] == rcpt) {
        userExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (userExists) {
    //Do something
}
```

This has the added benefit of not being vulnerable to regex-injection.

Comment: `rcpt` isn't actually an object in my code. It's just a variable. However, I'm considering your response as a way to work around this.

Comment: If `rcpt` is a variable, just remove the quotes.  Note that this is case sensitive.  If you don't want that, call `toUpperCase`.

Comment: Well, see, that is exactly what I did. However, the problem is that match() is confusing `joe-user` with `page-joe-user`. So, to replicate the problem...

Using `page-joe-user` and `joe-user` for example:

`$('#element').html().match(rcpt)` mostly works but if I click in `page-joe-user` first and then try and click in `joe-user` then match() triggers a match when they are, in fact, not (or don't want them to be). If I click them in the reverse order then all works well. So, to mitigate, I want to anchor my regex since this looks like typical regex greediness.

Comment: And I want to apologize. I see that I confused a crucial point that I'm match()'ing html.

Comment: There we go. That is a better solution and I've implemented it. Works well. Thank you.