# jQuery :contains with html

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table that contains comma separated lists of numbers like this: `<td>72,76,81</td>`. I'm trying to select the table cells that *don't* contain a particular number. This selector worked:

`$("td:not(:contains('76'))", $table)`

The issue is that there may be rows that contain '576' or '761', etc.

To solve that issue, I decided to put a `<span>` around each number, so that it's now: `<td><span>72</span>,<span>76</span>,<span>81</span></td>`. My selector is now:

`$("td:not(:contains('<span>76</span>'))", $table)`

When I debug this selector in Firebug, it's is returning some span tag that doesn't actually exist in the HTML source, instead of the correct `<td>`s.

Basically, putting the '`<span>`' in the `:contains()` string is breaking the selector. Is there any selector similar to `:contains()` that will work properly when HTML is passed to it? Or is there some way I can select by the entire string inside the `<span>`?

BTW, this site is using jquery 1.3.2.

Comment: No chance of using a not-horribly-out-of-date version of jQuery?

Comment: Someday.. it'll break several libraries, and I haven't been able to convince the client they should spend the money to upgrade yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stick with `<span>`s, this works, even with jQuery 1.3.2:

```
var $tds = $("table td").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).find('span').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === '76';
    }).length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/PFk8H/

---

On the other hand, it's actually really easy if you want to go back to the old markup:

```
var $tds = $("table td").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).text().match(/\b76\b/);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/L6AFz/

---

To use a variable in the regex, use the [`new RegExp(string)` constructor syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp):

```
var n = 76,
    re = new RegExp("\\b" + n + "\\b");

var $tds = $("table td").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).text().match(re);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/hKQH7/

Comment: please simplify regex like this `match(/\b76\b/)` meaning word boundary either side of 76

Comment: Option 2 here looks to me to be the best answer because it reduces the number of DOM elements. :) Problem, though, I am trying to pass a variable to the match() statement (obviously I'm not always looking for the number 76). `$(this).text().match('\b' + val + '\b')'` is returning undefined for me.. any ideas why? BTW I used this answer to put a variable in my regexp -- doesn't seem to be working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695633/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-regex-in-jquery-javascript/1695653#1695653

Answer (score 2):

try this:

<s>$("td span:not(:contains('76'))", $table).parent()</s>

```
$("td span", $table).filter(function(){return $(this).text() != '76';}).parent()
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also match '576' or '761'?

Comment: This totally works, thanks. I'm leaning towards using the answer that doesn't require the span tags if I can. :) If not then I'll accept yours..

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to use `:contains` for this.  As you've stated `:contains('76')` will match '76', '576', '761', etc.  You can try using `.filter` to get what you want.

```
$('td:has("span")').filter(function(){
    var x = true;
    $('span', this).each(function(){
        x = x && $(this).text() != '76';
    });
    return x;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KvK3J/

Answer (score 1):

Tested with jQuery 1.2.6

http://jsfiddle.net/G27JF/4/

```
$("td>span").filter(function() { 
    return ($(this).text() != 76);
}).parent().css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Comment: Do you realize that using `% 76` means that it will accept multiples of 76?

Comment: ...again, this has the same problem that @Rocket's answer had. You're now selecting spans, not tds.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to match the insides of the table row. First iterate over all the elements then ignore the ones that match the regex

Here is a basic one that will match:

```
/^76$/g
```

check out [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to build more regex.

Comment: I think this would also match other numbers that contain '76'.. ?

Comment: I miss read where the data was. But it would work if you were matching the value of the table row.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the 'Contains' issue, you would make them as classes:

```
<span class="76"></span>
```

And:

```
$("td:not(:has(span.76)"), $table)
```

This could be adjusted to have multiples in 1 object too as:

```
<span class="76 77 78"></span>
```

Or even put in the TD itself simplifying the selector even more

```
$("td:not(.76 .77, $table)
```

Comment: This would still match '576' and '761'.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't convert the values to classes, because all of the cells in the table are output by the same PHP loop, and some of the cells contain product names, which might be lengthy, contain quotes, etc.