# How can I select a block of text on a page, then move an element in front of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that will appear on the page at a separate point. It doesn't always appear on the page and can be added via a CMS if needed. There's a line of text that will appear within the body. If the user has decided to have this div added, it would need to be moved into position via jquery. So, I have this text:

```
<p><strong>Key Facts:</strong></p>
```

I want to find it using jquery, then move the other div in front of it. I tried a couple of different ways to select this text then move the div in front of it and haven't had any luck. The best way I found to find the text was to do this:

```
var foundin = $('*:contains("<p><strong>Key Facts:</strong></p>")');
```

From that point, to move the div into position, I thought I could something like this:

```
$('#DivIWantToMove').insertBefore($foundin);
```

That didn't work, though. I also looked at this:

```
$( $foundin ).before( $('#DivIWantToMove') );
```

AS you might imagine, since you're reading this, that didn't work either. So, I'm asking you, is it possible to do what I want? I'm fairly constrained by the CMS that we are using. The DIV I need to move will always be someplace on the page and I have to move it. The client doesn't want to have to add a class to `<p><strong>Key Facts:</strong></p>` so I'm let with this. If I could have a class on `<p>` then it would be super easy. I've already done it. The client doesn't like having an extra step. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to add a class on in <p> dynamically whenever the given condition met?

Comment: I don't have to. I just know that, if the class is on the `<p>` initially, it's a cakewalk to move the div in front of it. But, as it stands now, I can select the paragraph, but moving the div in front of it doesn't work.

If I add a class to the `<p>` dynamically, would that do the trick you think?

I tried an experiment on this page here and it doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: one problem is collection of `$('*:contains(...')` will return every parent up the tree from that text. Is it always in a `<strong>` tag? Always in `<p>` tag too?

Comment: That one particular string should only appear once on the page. I'm looking for that one particular block of HTML and if it's not there then I won't place the doc on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `contains` selector only looks for text, not html tags. so you have to modify your contains selector. if your html is like this -

```
<div>
    <p><strong>Key Facts:</strong>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="move">something something</div>
```

and you want to move your `<div id='move'>` in front of `p`, then try this -

```
var foundin = $('p:contains("Key Facts")');
var divtomove = $('div#move');
foundin.before(divtomove);
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Mju6/)</kbd>

**Update** also look into this QA: [jQuery :contains with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571329/jquery-contains-with-html). Instead of using `contains` you can use one of the methods from there.

Comment: This worked perfect. I see what I was doing wrong now. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.