# JavaScript Regular Expression with character class quantifier variable

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, replace, quantifiers

I am trying to create a regular expression with a character class that has a specific quantifier which is a variable for example:

```
var str = "1234.00";
var quantifier = 3;
str = str.replace(/(\d)(\d{quantifier}\.)/,"$1,$2");
//str should be "1,234.00"
```

This works as follows (without a variable):

```
var str = "1234.00";
str = str.replace(/(\d)(\d{3}\.)/,"$1,$2");
//str == "1,234.00"
```

However it does not have the same functionality with a [quoted pattern instead of a slash-delimited pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695633/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-regex-in-jquery-javascript) as follows:

```
var str = "1234.00";
str = str.replace("(\d)(\d{3}\.)","$1,$2");
//str == "1234.00" - not "1,234.00"
//quote symbol choice does not change this
str = str.replace('(\d)(\d{3}\.)',"$1,$2");
//str == "1234.00" - not "1,234.00"
```

edit: to be more clear I have added a summary question which was answered below:
**How do I create a regular expression with an interpolated variable from a quoted string?**

Although my preference would be to use interpolation, it seems that is not available (at least in this context), and is not necessary.

I have also tried to come up with a way to [concatenate/join some regex literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185510/how-can-i-concatenate-regex-literals-in-javascript) to achieve the same result, but have been unable to do so for this use case.

As a side note - I am familiar with this type of regular expression in perl:

```
my $str = "1234.00";
my $quantifier = 3;
$str =~ s/(\d)(\d{$quantifier}\.)/$1,$2/;
# $str eq "1,234.00"
```

Which can be made useful as follows:

```
my $str = "1234567890.00";
for my $quantifier (qw(9 6 3)) {
    $str =~ s/(\d)(\d{$quantifier}\.)/$1,$2/;
}
# $str eq "1,234,567,890.00"
```

**With the suggestions/answers provided I have created a sample currency string prototype as follows:**

```
String.prototype.toCurrency = function() {
    var copy = parseFloat(this).toFixed(2);
    for (var times = parseInt(copy.length/3); times > 0; times--) {
        var digits = times * 3;
        var re = new RegExp("(\\d)(\\d{" + digits + "}\\.)");
        copy = copy.replace(re,"$1,$2");
    }
    return '$'+copy;
};
str = "1234567890";
str.toCurrency();
// returns "$1,234,567,890.00"
```

Comment: The second question you refer to basically contains the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with this statement:

```
str.replace("(\d)(\d{3}\.)","$1,$2");
```

The first is that you are passing a string and not a regular expression object, and the second is that within a string literal the backslash has a special meaning to escape certain things (e.g., `"\n"` is a newline) so to have an actual backslash in your string literal you need to double it as `"\\"`. Using the `RegExp()` constructor to create a regex object from a string you get this:

```
str.replace(new RegExp("(\\d)(\\d{3}\\.)"),"$1,$2");
```

So from there you can do this:

```
var quantifier = 3
str = str.replace(new RegExp("(\\d)(\\d{" + quantifier + "}\\.)"),"$1,$2");
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the string vs regular expression object -- would upvote if I could.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can't concatenate or interpolate into regex literals, *but* you can create a regex from a string by using [the `RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('(\\d)(\\d{' + quantifier + '}\\.'), "$1,$2");
```

Note, by the way, that this:

```
str.replace(..., ...);
```

has no effect, because `replace` doesn't modify a string, but rather, it returns a copy of the string with the replacements made. So you need to write this:

```
str = str.replace(..., ...);
```

instead.

Comment: Edited above to use the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a RegExp object:

```
var str = "1234.00";
var digits = 2;
var re = new RegExp("(\\d)(\\d{" + digits + "})");
var str2 = str.replace(re,"$1,$2-");
```

`str2` would contain `1,23-4.00`.

Working example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/JuZtc/

Note that you need to escape `\` in strings, thus `\\`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting escaping the \ character.  That was what I needed.