# JavaScript using a variable with .match Regex Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

I'm pretty new to regex but I'm trying to use a variable inside my match.

So I have a string that is "Total: $168"
I'm trying to get the number amount, 168.

So I have this:

```
totalCost = totalCost.match(/[^Total: $]*$/);
```

when i echo that out I get 168.
This is working, this is what I want.

But now I want to take it one step further and want to make "Total: $" a variable so I can easily set it and make this modular.

So I did

```
 var stringToSearch = 'Total: $';
```

and then did

```
 totalCost = totalCost.match(/[^stringToSearch]*$/);
```

I do a console log of:

```
 console.log(totalCost+" || "+stringToSearch );
```

and I get:

```
l: $168 || Total: $
```

Why when I make this variable it behaves all weird?

Comment: Are you aware, that `[^stringToSearch]` means any character, that is not one of that's `stringToSearch` composed of (inside  a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)). If you just want to match digits at the end use `\d+$` or `[0-9]+$`

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What is the value of `totalCost` when you do `totalCost = totalCost.match(/[^Total: $]*$/);`? It would be nice to have a block of commented code explaining what you're doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you [can't interpolate into a JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695633/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-regex-in-jquery-javascript). `/[^stringToSearch]*$/` would match any substring ending with characters other than those in the literal string `"stringToSearch"`. If you want to be modular, you can use the `RegExp` constructor:

```
totalCost = totalCost.match(new RegExp("[^" + stringToSearch + "]*$"));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Wish I knew RegExp existed. I was wondering if there was a function to convert a string into a regex expression so I could pop that into the match but I couldn't find one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's pure luck that your regex worked to return `"120"`!

`[^Total: $]*$` tells the regex parser to match anything *other* than the characters between the brackets `[`..`]` ('T','o','t','a','l',' ', or '$'), as many times as possible up to the end of the line (`$` not a literal '$' character in this case). So what did it match? The only characters that fell outside of those in the character class: '1','2','0'.

What you were trying to do was capture the matched number after the literal string 'Total: $':

```
var totalCost = 'Total: $168',
    matches = totalCost.match(/^Total: \$([\d\.]*)/),
    totalCostNum = matches ? parseFloat(matches[1]) : 0;
```

To make that variable, you'll need to first *escape* your variable so the text can be matched literally and then use `new RegExp` to build your regex:

```
var totalCost = 'Total: $168',
    stringToMatch = 'Total: $',
    stringToMatchEscaped = stringToMatch.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'),
    stringToMatchRegEx = new RegExp(stringToMatchEscaped + /([\d\.]*)/.source),
    matches = totalCost.match(stringToMatchRegEx),
    totalCostNum = matches ? parseFloat(matches[1]) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make your **regex** into a variable you can use on different inputs. Try something like this:

```
var regex = /^Total: \$(\d+)/;
regex.exec('Total: $168');
// [ 'Total: $168', '168', index: 0, input: 'Total: $168' ]
regex.exec('Total: $123');
// [ 'Total: $123', '123', index: 0, input: 'Total: $123' ]
```

There are also some problems with the logic of your regex, which I have changed in my example. It's not matching as you expect.