# javascript regexp help passing in a var to be included as part of the match

Tags: javascript, regex

Need some help from you javascript regexp pro's

I have a function that I want to pass in some a "value" and a list of accepted characters.  This function works in php, but the javascript variables don't work the same as in php, so I need some guiadance.

I would like to call this function like this:

```
isAlphaNumeric(myValue, "_-");
```

This would allow any number, or letter as well as the underscore and the hyphen, but no other characters

This is the function I have, but doesn't quite work right.

```
function isAlphaNumeric(value, allow)
{
    var result = /^[A-Za-z0-9+allow+]+$/.test(value);
    return result;
}
```

How can I accomplish what I'm after?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use RegExp object constructor

```
function isAlphaNumeric(value, allow)
{
    var re = new RegExp( '^[A-Za-z0-9'+allow+']+$');
    var result = re.test(value);
    return result;
}
```

or

```
function isAlphaNumeric(value, allow)
{
    return new RegExp( '^[A-Za-z0-9'+allow+']+$').test(value);
}
```

Comment: You'll want to escape `allow` as well.

Comment: @Box9 "allow" is not coming from end users, so we'll let that pass

Comment: @cyber, in the question the example given for `allow` was `"_-"`, which *does* need escaping ;)

Comment: @Box - really? even though it is encapsulated in `^[..]` ?

Comment: @cyberwiki: JS seems to allow it, but in most PCRE, if you wish to include the dash `-` in a character class, it has to come first. (Due to it's role as a range operator.)

Comment: @cyber, sorry, not for that particular example, as a `-` on the end seems to work, but you'll run into problems if another character was added, which will make `-` a special character.

Comment: @Orbling - or last, as in this case. @Box9 - caller can do the escaping.

Answer (score 1):

By creating a `RegExp()` object.

```
function isAlphaNumeric(value, allow) {
    var re = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9' + (allow ? allow : '') + ']+$');

    return re.test(value);
}
```

Comment: (allow ? allow : '') appears to be redundant

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Not so, it stops things like undefined and nulls mucking up the string concatenation.

Comment: @cyberwiki: Just because the results come back the same, does not mean it is doing it right, worth looking at what it does to the regexp, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/ASVvW/2/

Comment: lol .. it does work for the question though, since both "null" and "undefined" are contained in `A-Za-z`. Luck

Comment: @cyberwiki: Exactly, luck saved the day for you.  However, it is *always* good practice to validate incoming values to functions.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't handle variables inside strings/regexs directly. You have to create the Regex using the constructor like this:

```
function isAlphaNumeric(value, allow)
{
    var result = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9" + allow + "]+$").test(value);
    return result;
}
```

Tested on: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLdtw/

Check [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185510/how-can-i-concatenate-regex-literals-in-javascript) for more info on this concatenation.