# Javascript RegExp different results from constructor and literal

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking into creating different Regular Expressions, looking for strong and medium strength user passwords, and I have noticed that the same expression gives different results (using lookaheads, backrefrence and negative lookaheads) depending on if I use the `RegExp` constructor or the literal syntax.

I have tested on IE and Firefox and created a little example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4z4gxxkL/

The reason I was using the `RegExp` constructor was that I am storing my expressions in JSON as strings - But in the case of passwords, I can use literal syntax.

All my other expressions are quite simple and produce expected results. Can somebody explain what is going on here? Is this a ECMAScript standards issue?

I always tend to use http://regexr.com/ to test my Regex

I discovered this discrepancy by preforming a test on "abc123" using `RegExp("^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*(.)\1).{5,}$", "g")` that gave `false`, however a test using `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*(.)\1).{5,}$/g` gave `true`

Comment: post your regex and the input here.

Comment: For an in-depth discussion of whats going on here, see my answer to a very similar question: [Building regexp from JS variables not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6803651/433790)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating regex instance from `RegExp` constructor, you need to escape the `\` with another `\` as it is a escape-sequence.

The first one works right, because there is no `\` in the `String`, whereas in others, it is there, *unescaped*.

[**Escaped Version**](http://jsfiddle.net/4z4gxxkL/3/)

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien happens :-)

Comment: You deserve a cookie.