# How to concatenate two regulars expressions

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I concatenate regex literals in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185510/how-can-i-concatenate-regex-literals-in-javascript)

I have two regulars expressions in my hand. A and B what i want to do is that, my expression should start with A and then finish with B how can i do that.

A=[^a-zA-Z] and B=/.+/;

Comment: A is not a regular expression.

Comment: @kennebec: `I have two regulars expressions in my hand. A and B...`

Comment: You mean you want to make one regex that has both characteristics, or you want to *dynamically, programmatically generate* a new regex based on two other ones?

Answer (score 0):

/* There are a lot of ways to go wrong with regular expressions-
this method ignores any flags in the first expression,
and doesn't check for errors-  It is safer to write your regular expressions whole,
or build them up from strings. */

```
function mergeRx(start, end){
    start= String(start).substring(1);
    end= String(end).substring(1);
    var rx=/\/([igm]+)?$/,
    flag= end.match(/[igm]+$/) || '';

    start= start.replace(rx, '')+end.replace(rx, '');
    return RegExp(start, flag);
}

var A=/[^a-zA-Z]/, B=/.+/;
mergeRx(A, B)

/*  returned value: (RegExp)
/[^a-zA-Z].+/
*/
```