# node.js express routes using new RegExp

Tags: express

Why this router works

```
app.get(/regularExpression/, function (req, res, next) {
});
```

But this don't work `Cannot GET`

```
var regularExpressionString = "regularExpressionString";    
var regularExpression = new RegExp(regularExpressionString);

app.get(regullarExpression, function (req, res, next) {
});
```

I need the second variant because I want to reuse router string parts according to DRY principle without repeating code. But when I use `/regularExpression/` I [cannot concat strings like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185510/how-can-i-concatenate-regex-literals-in-javascript) `/regularExpressionString1 + regularExpressionString2/`.

So **how** to concat strings in node.js express regex route?

## update

`new RegExp` works if I don't use special symbols like `\d` or `\w`

For example this pattern works:

```
regex = new RegExp('/(32)teeth')
```

But this don't:

```
regex = new RegExp('/(\d+)teeth')
```

Comment: The second variant should work as well. Ensure that you navigate in your browser to `/regularExpressionString`, not just `/regularExpression`

Comment: @CuriousGuy thank you. Simple regular expression like `new RegExp('/regularExpressionString')` really works. But when I try to use `\d` or `\s` it fails. `Cannot GET`. Please see my update above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape `\` symbol when using `RegExp` constructor, so it would be:

```
regex = new RegExp('/(\\d+)teeth')
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp