# Javascript. Problems with making regexp object from working regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a string in my js code, that actually is an html code.
It's started with `<li class='list__item item item_archive'>`
This works fine:

```
liMatches=s.match(/(<li[A-Za-z\s_=\']+>...$/);
```

where `s` is html string. Now I need to use RegExp object.

```
liMatchesRegex=new RegExp("<li[\s]+");
```

I create this object (I tried `<li[A-Za-z\s_=\']+>` too).

```
liMatchesConcat=s.match(liMatchesRegex);
```

shows me null
It works only with `liMatchesRegex=new RegExp("<li");`
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object using the literal notation:

```
var re = /<li[\s]+/;
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the constructor and pass in a string, you need to escape the backslashes (`\\`) in your expression:

```
var re = new RegExp('<li[\\s]+');
```

Comment: I can't use literal notation because I need a concatination of regex. As I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185510/how-can-i-concatenate-regex-literals-in-javascript It's only possible with regexp object. So I see, I should use two backslashes instead of one. Gonna check it.