# find text in string with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the string in this format

`var text = '{"STATUS_NEW":"12345678","STATUS_OLD":"87654321","TEXT":"blahblah"}';`

to parse this string, i'm use this code:

```
var pattern = /"STATUS_NEW":"12345678"/;
var exists = pattern.test(text);
if(exists){console.log('ok');}
```

All work fine! console get me "ok". But I need to paste my var into 'pattern'. I tried this:

```
var status = '12345678'; var pattern = /"STATUS_NEW":"/ + status + /"/; //not work!
```

I tried to set 'status' without quotes, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with a string, which you concatinate.

```js
var text = '{"STATUS_NEW":"12345678","STATUS_OLD":"87654321","TEXT":"blahblah"}',
    status = '12345678',
    pattern = new RegExp('"STATUS_NEW":"' + status + '"'),
    exists = pattern.test(text);

if (exists){
    console.log('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/185529/3711952 you have to do something like:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("some regex segment" + /*comment here */
              segment_part + /* that was defined just now */
              "another segment");
```

So in your case it will be:

```
var status = '12345678'; 
var pattern = new RegExp(/"STATUS_NEW":"/ + status + /"/);
```