# Why does this javascript RegExp concatenation not work

Tags: javascript

The goal is to replace digits 0-9 as well as a variable value from a text input in a form, with a substitute value of x if a match is found, as user types, using javascript.

Why does this not work?

`regexExpression = "([0-9]" + companyvalue + ")";`

Each case works when coded independently but does not work when concatenated.

`var regexExpression = ("[0-9]");` Works as expected and substitutes x for numeric value.

`var regexExpression = "("companyvalue")";` Works as expected and substitutes x for the variable text input value.

```js
function clean(e) {
 var companyvalue = document.getElementById("company").value;
 var textfield = document.getElementById(e);
 var regexExpression = ('([0-9]' + companyvalue + ')');
 var regex = new RegExp(regexExpression,"g","i");
  if(textfield.value.search(regex) > -1) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Telephone numbers and company name<br>are automatically redacted.";
 }
 textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "x");
 //alert (companyvalue);
 }
```

```html
<input id="company" style="border-color:#F8980F;" class="medium required" type="text" name="company" />

<textarea id="description" onkeyup="clean('description')" onkeydown="clean('description')" class="medium" cols="25" rows="8" name="description" placeholder="Write a short summary." /></textarea>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate regex literals in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185510/how-can-i-concatenate-regex-literals-in-javascript)

Comment: Are the words separated by a space at input string? _"Each case works when coded independently but does not work when concantenated."_ Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Input string is a single word with no whitespace but you raise an interesting point as there may be cases where more than one word is used. I will edit my question to include a snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description) for an in depth explanation.

But basically, you can create a regular expression using literal notation:

```
/([0-9])/
```

Or using a `RegExp` constructor:

```
new RegExp('([0-9])');
```

Given that you're wanting to dynamically build your pattern, you need to use the constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp('([0-9]' + companyvalue + ')');
```

**Edit:** Check out this example: https://jsbin.com/zekovuqemi/edit?js,output

Comment: I have used the constructor as you suggested. I will edit my post to include a snippet as a better explanation.

Comment: The example you provided works perfectly. Appreciated. Please can you explain the purpose of the pipe operator in the following new RegExp('([0-9])|(' + company.value + ')', 'gi');

Comment: The `|` is an OR. You don't want to match a number followed by the company name, you want to match and replace numbers OR the company name.

Answer (score 0):

Check out below solution :

`var pattern1 = '[0-9]';
var regex = new RegExp(pattern1 + companyvalue, "g");`

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same as mine when using your suggestion. The numeric value is correctly replaced but not the string value. If I write the result of the string to an alert or to document the value is correct so it is being correctly passed to the argument.

Comment: Here what I have used : `var pattern1 = '[0-9]';
var pattern2 = "abc";
var regex = new RegExp(pattern1 + pattern2, "g");
// at this point, the line above is the same as: var regex = /#abc#/g;

var input = "Hello 8abc world 7abc again.";
var output = input.replace(regex, "!!");
alert(output); // Hello !! world !! again.` And it is correctly replaced string with number.